# Grothendieck fibrations via right lifting property

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, model-categories

The class of Grothendieck fibrations is a subclass of isofibrations, which constitute the class of fibrations in the canonical model structure on $Cat$. Is there any characterization of Grothendieck fibrations in terms of lifting properties? If so, is there a model structure on $Cat$ (of course, non-canonical), whose fibrations are precisely Grothendieck fibrations?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but the Grothendieck fibration property is of the form $\forall\exists\forall\exists$, whereas lifting properties are usually of the form $\forall\exists$, so it seems complicated to me (but this is just heuristically speaking)